# Nested IF else statement in C

Tags: c

I can't seem to locate the problem in my program where it says, "error: expected declaration or statement at the end of input"

I would like to learn more about this mistake

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float Math, English, Science, Fundamentals, per;
    
    printf("Enter GPA of 4 subject\n");
    scanf("%f %f %f %f", &Math, &English, &Science, &Fundamentals);
    
    per = (Math + English + Science + Fundamentals) / 4.0;
    
    if(per >= 5)
    {
        printf("Your GWA is: 75\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if(per >= 3)
        {    
            printf("Your GWA is: 75\n");
        }
        else
        {
            if(per >= 2)
            {
                printf("Your GWA is: 85\n");
            }
            else
            {
                if(per >= 1)
                {
                      printf("Your GWA is: 100\n");
                }
            }
        }        
        
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: please post your whole code as text instead of screenshot, and the location of error would help. is it possible you're missing a `}` at the end?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Providing the necessary details, including your MRE, compiler warnings and associated errors, and sample data if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: You are missing a single `}`, presumably before the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have 8 opening braces but only 7 closing braces.

If we assume, that the return statement should be the last statement in your code, then the end of your code should look like this:

```
    } // end last else
    return 0;
} // end main
```

And, have you ever heard of the `else if` construct:

```
     if (per >= 5) {...}
else if (per >= 3) {...}
else if (per >= 2) {...}
else if (per >= 1) {...}
else               {...}
```